# Will assigning at tag to a Github Release also assign it to the Commit

Tags: git, github, tags, release

Will assigning at tag (e.g. v1.1.0) to a Github `release` also assign it to the `commit`, assuming that the specified `commit` doesn't already have a tag?  If so, will it be a `lightweight` or `annotated` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will assigning at tag (e.g. v1.1.0) to a Github `release` also assign it to the `commit`

Yes it will.

> If so, will it be a `lightweight` or `annotated` tag?

A lightweight one.

---

You can take a look at this **[sample release](https://github.com/nulltoken/libgit2sharp.voron/releases/tag/v0.1)** that I've created through GitHub UI for the sake of answering this question. This repository wasn't previously bearing any tag.

Once locally fetched, one can see that a new tag has been added upstream.

```
$ ls .git/refs/tags/
v0.1
```

And that this tag directly points to a commit (ie. It's a lightweight tag, not an annotated one).

```
$ cat .git/refs/tags/v0.1
485750d2def0e01f5653534659d1785be0ff73db

$ git cat-file -t 48575
commit
```