# Can I create "releases" in git like I can when using github?

Tags: git, github

Both when using git ( and when I say this I mean a git repository that I host ) and when using github (which I also use for different projects ) I know that I can create tags ( which I tend to think of as releases / snapshots of a branch at a moment in time, that cannot be changed ).

However I noticed recently that on github I can now create "releases". These appear to consist of a tag and then some labelling (maybe this is just syntactic sugar or maybe its a much more complex beast ).

As an example if I created a tag on git or github via the command line using the following:

```
git tag -a 2.1 -m "Fixed AI problems in Skynet" master
git push --tags
```

Then this does indeed create a tag but not a "release" (obviously). In the github GUI I can then turn this into a "release" with a few clicks.

However I cannot seem to find a way to do this in regular git ( i.e. the git repo I host ).

Is it possible to create "releases" in git or should I just be happy with tags ? and as a further sub question: is the release concept in github that builds upon tags just something they came up with to make the tagging process more slick ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Releases` in github are just `tags` with some attached binary assets (and a lot of nice UI features).  See [the github blog](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) for an exact description.

Creating tags is a very appropriate way to mark a release in a git repository.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create "releases" in git or should I just be happy with tags

A `Release` is a GitHub concept. It cannot be created through a git command line. However, it's built on top of the git tag concept.

Basically, a `Release` is made of

- A git tag
- A release note
- Some downloadable artifacts

More information about this topic:

- GitHub Blog post **[announcement](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software)**
- GitHub Help **[topic](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases)**
- Related **[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048947/will-assigning-at-tag-to-a-github-release-also-assign-it-to-the-commit/23053235#23053235)** that elaborates a bit further on the gory details of tagging.